# Transforming ffmpeg code to batch process files in linux

Tags: video, encoding, ffmpeg, scripting

I need help converting ffmpeg command to so I can batch process the files

```
ffmpeg -i in.mkv -vf subtitles=in.mkv:si=0 -c:v libx264 -c:a copy -map 0:v -map 0:a:0 out.mp4
```

Convert everything in the folder to same name as the .mkv file but to .mp4. The file name can have [ ] _ and spaces. So I will really appreciate if any one can help me and explain the process!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming bash shell (you didn't mention OS, but this will work on macOS or Linux). This just does a basic copy/transcode, you'll want to adjust the parameters to match your desired manipulation

```
for i in *.mkv; do 
    ffmpeg -i "$i" -c copy "${i/%.mkv/.mp4}"
done
```

Comment: It's on macOS mostly, but I also plan to use it on Debian. What should I put for the subtitle name field? "$i" or  ${i/%.mp4/.mkv} ? It will be converting from .mkv to .mp4 if you are wondering

Comment: if you want to match the input filename $i, the second option substitutes the .mkv extension for .mp4 (sorry, misread the direction in original question so have corrected)